# Prepopulate tabularinline with value from related lookup in manytomany field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have question to ask. I want to have my `change_form` to prepopulate the tabularinline from intances' value of related looks up (use manytomany field). So when I search `kode_prod` in `change_form` in class `Order`, I could get its instance and prepopulate all in my tabularinline (class `Foo`).

here is my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    tax_per_item = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    discount_per_item = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))


class Order(models.Model):
    produks = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name=u"Kode Produk")
    no_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_kode_cust')


class Foo(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, editable=False)
    pemesanan = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    tax = models.IntegerField()
```

Class `Order` is manytomanyfield relationship to `Product`, so that in `change_form` I can get its instance with related looksup. Class `Foo` is intermediary that comes to tabularinline in `change_form`. So, are there some ways for me to do that ? Please help me and thank you for your kindly responses :).

Comment: Could you please add your models with the question related fields?

Comment: Done, i've editted. Please give me some responses :). Thank you :).

Comment: Alright. Now please delete all fields that are not relevant to this question. Then please explain what field you want to prepopulate and from what field(s) exactly.

Comment: Oke, i've editted all again. Sorry for the inconvinience :D. I wanna prepopulate all field as i stated above in Class Product to tabularinline Class Foo (price in Product to Price in Foo and so on) in change_form Order. I've made a form above the inline. The form contains related lookup manytomany field produks (from class Order). After the form i've made submit button too, so that, if i search produks (by related lookup), i can click submit and prepopulate all instances to inline. But i don't know how i can get that instances from submit button. Do you know how ? Thank you once again :).

Comment: oke then, but quantity field in Class Foo are not populated. Only price, discount and tax field in Class Foo that i want to be populated from price, tax_per_item and discount_per_item from class Product. Hope this is clear for you :(. Thank you for your kindly responses :).

Comment: Ok. We're getting closer :D But I still don't understand exactly what you mean. You wrote tabular inline. That means, that you are trying to do the prepopulation in Django admin, right? But if so, what do you mean with you made a submit button?

Comment: yes that's what i mean. Submit button is for getting the instances (price, discount and tax from class Product) from related lookup and pass them to tabularinline (class Foo - class intermediary of manytomany). It's all clear ? Thank you very much :).

Comment: to make it easier, i've uploaded the UI for change_form class Order in http://upload.ui.ac.id/?a=d&i=186467 :). Thank you for your kindly responses :).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the Screenshot. Seems pretty straight forward. But where is the submit button you talked about?? I see the default `Save` buttons...

Comment: Oh, sorry i missed the right screenshot. here it is. http://upload.ui.ac.id/?a=d&i=119103. The submit button is under all fieldset and upper the tabularinline. Thank you very much :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably write a jQuery script that is called when a `kode_prod` is entered, when the page loads or when the "Add another Foo" link is clicked. You don't even need your custom submit button, since you can register an event listener for the `'blur'` event.

You script sends an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest which is answered by a django view like that:

```
from django.core import serializers

def get_product(request, pk):
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("xml", Product.objects.filter(pk=pk)))
```

Then in your jQuery script in the response handler populate all needed fields from the response.

Next time please be a lot more specific and clear in your question.

Comment: Oh, i see. It seems that i must learn how to use jquery. By the way, thank you very much for your kindly responses. Im sorry for my unspecific and unclear question :D.

Answer (score 0):

do you need an relationship between `Order` and `Product` through `Foo`?
then [django-documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) might help you

Comment: Not really. Ive read it all over again and again, but the docs can't help me much with this question :(.