# Problems with submit button in change_form template Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, submit

im new with Django and Python, and im still confuse about how to prepopulate values from manytomany field related lookup as my question in [Prepopulate tabularinline with value from related lookup in manytomany field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975362/prepopulate-tabularinline-with-value-from-related-lookup-in-manytomany-field) 
here is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    tax_per_item = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    discount_per_item = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))


class Order(models.Model):
    produks = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name=u"Kode Produk")
    no_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_kode_cust')

    def order_view(request):
        if 'enter' in request.POST:
            #response to tabular.html template
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/POS/Pemesanan/inline')

class Foo(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, editable=False)
    pemesanan = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    tax = models.IntegerField()
```

and here is my admin:

```
class PemesananAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fieldsets = (
    ('Customer in Time (Person)', {
        'fields': ('no_customer',),
    }),
    ('Date', {
        'fields' : ('date', 'delivery_date',),
    }),
    ('Order Details', {
        'fields' : ('produks',),
    }),
)
search_fields = ['produks', 'no_customer']
raw_id_fields = ('produks', 'no_customer',)
related_lookup_fields = {
'fk': ['no_customer'],
'm2m': ['produks'],
}
inlines = [
    FooInline,
]

class FooInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = Foo
template = 'admin/POS/Pemesanan/inline/tabular.html'
extra = 0
allow_add = True
```

and here is my change_form override template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}{{ block.super }}

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

But, still nobody can tell me how :(. (If you please response to my question on that page). And now, im confusing about 2 problems:
1. I want my submit button in change_form to redirect to change_form too a.k.a in the same page need no refresh page (not to change_list page or the actual submission).
2. How can i get instances of related lookup 'produks' fieldset (manytomany) from submit button so that i can access parent values (Class Product) and prepopulate all to tabularinline (Class Foo or intermediary class)?

FYI, submit button is below all fieldsets.

Anyone help me please :(. Thank you for your kindly responses :).

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

will just send your submit-button back to your server.
the form-tag needs to sorround every form-element.

just remove: `<form action="" method="post">` and `</form>`
and it may work.

Comment: Oh i see, i've removed it. But now my problem is, how can i get instances from fieldset "Kode Produk" (produks manytomany field) and then pass them to my intermediary model Foo ? Sorry if im too much asking you, thank you :).

Comment: this is what stackoverflow is all about :) i'm here to serve your question :)

Comment: does 'admin/POS/Pemesanan/inline/tabular.html' extends 'admin/edit_inline/tabular.html'?

Comment: Oh yap, i want to extends 'admin/edit_inline/tabular.html' so that i can prepopulate to the field in tabularinline after i click enter button (same with my question before :D.). But now, still i don't know how. I've searched before, one article say that i must use javascript. But again, im really a newbie ;(. Do you know how ? thank you :D.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you correctly you want to display an order (`Order`) and its items (`Foo`)?

my naive solution would be:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   ...

class Order(models.Model):
   products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Item')

class Item(models.Model):
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   quantity = models.IntegerField()
   ...
```

and the admin could be as simple as this:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ItemInline,)
```

you need to test that, as i cant (actually)

Comment: No, not really like that :D. But i want to display all values from Product (get by related lookup in fieldset "Kode Produk" in the UI i've posted on my question before :D.) to inline Item in change_form class Order. Sorry if my question is unclear for you ;( Thank you very much :).